# Переход со $scope на this as

Tags: angularjs

Не могу никак разобраться, как с обычного синтаксиса контроллера через `$scope` перейти на синтаксис Controller AS. Задачу упростил для примера.

Есть работающий код в стиле `$scope` ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2X4cIpTkVS4u7QBBlW4h)):

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-hide="!isLoading">isLoading</div><br>
    <my-frame ng-repeat="item in items"></my-frame>
    <button ng-click="add('1')">ADD</button>
  </body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive("myFrame", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    template: "<iframe src='load.html'></iframe>",
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('load', function () {
        scope.$apply(function (){
          scope.$parent.$parent.isLoading = false;  
        });
      });
    }
  }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.isLoading = false;
  $scope.add = function (value){
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    $scope.items.push(value);
  };
});
```

пытаюсь его переделать на CONTROLLER AS

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
    <div ng-hide="!ctrl.isLoading">isLoading</div><br>
    <my-frame ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items"></my-frame>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.add('1')">ADD</button>
  </body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive("myFrame", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    template: "<iframe src='load.html'></iframe>",
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('load', function () {
        scope.$apply(function (){
          scope.$parent.$parent.isLoading = false;  
        });
      });
    }
  }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  this.items = [];
  this.isLoading = false;
  this.add = function (value){
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.items.push(value);
  };
});
```

И не работает как хотелось бы: свойство isLoading в экземпляре контроллера не меняется. соответственно не скрывается DIV isloading. Возможно ли заставить одинаково работать? я понимаю, что проблема в директиве, в link, но как сделать иначе?

Answer (score 1):

Если просто, то в `add` - `this` уже не `this`.
А если серьезно, то вот [отличное руководство по стилю](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) для AngularJS. Там есть примеры для контроллеров и всего прочего.

В вашем примере немного исправил и все заработало:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.items = [];
  ctrl.isLoading = false;

  ctrl.add = function (value){
    ctrl.isLoading = true;
    ctrl.items.push(value);
  };     

});
```